# Problem running "selinux sandbox" with java

Tags: rhel, java, selinux, sandbox

I am trying to sandbox a java application using selinux sandbox.

*System details*: Redhat 6 | x86_64 | no x server install | jdk7 from oracle tar.gz version | cgred and cgconfig are stop

The cmd (run as root)

```
 sandbox /root/jdk/bin/java -version
```

above cmd failed with

```
 /root/jdk/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Digging, revealed that "libjli.so" is RPATH shared library. so i thought ok since sandbox is copying my bin/java to /tmp/sandbox_random therefore a hardcode path will not be found.

Then i change the RPATH using "`chrpath`" utility and changed it to a hardcode value
But still it showed the same error.

Then i used the -M -i option of sandbox and ran following command (i included all the .so file it complaint about):

```
sandbox -M -i /root/jdk/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so -i /root/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so -i /root/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg -i /root/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so -i    /root/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so -i /root/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so /root/jdk/bin/java  -version
```

Following command resulted in this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007fb039000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Permission denied' (errno=13)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/hs_err_pid1270.log
```

Now i used the strace to see what happened and strace printed(small section)

```
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fb15b6359d0) = 8268
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 1048576)                    = 0
close(3)                                = 0
wait4(8268, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f4579000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Permission denied' (errno=13)
```

I have enough space for sure

***Can you guys please indicate what might be wrong ?***

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is Resolved**. It turn out to be that the labeling of the file related to java(both openjdk and oracle java) was not correct in my redhat 6 system.
When i upgraded from redhat 6 to redhat 7 it started working all fine i.e 
`sandbox java -version` worked perfectly with no problems.

In my redhat 7 system the .so and other java related file are labeled as one of the following:

```
system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t:s0
system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0
```

in my earlier machine i.e redhat 6 all file were marked as something differently and hence i was getting the issue.